# featuretools progress bar when running dfs

Tags: featuretools

When using [featuretools](https://docs.featuretools.com/index.html) is there a way to show a progress bar when running [dfs](https://docs.featuretools.com/automated_feature_engineering/afe.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the parameter `verbose=True` in the [dfs](https://docs.featuretools.com/generated/featuretools.dfs.html#featuretools.dfs) function call should give you a progress bar.